# Restarting explorer.exe process for all logged users on Windows to enforce SRP rules

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to intercept certain signal in a windows service, and then find all `explorer.exe` processes and restart them.

So far it works fine if only one user is logged into the system and the service is in "*foreground*" mode, e.g - started as process for the **current** user. Explorer is killed and restarted just fine. However if there are multiple users - the `explorer` is killed but started only for the **current** user.

Moreover, as a service - there is a different user that owns the service itself, and while killing explorer works fine - it can't be started most of the time, and if starts - it is started for the **service** user only.

With some digging in Win32 API it seems possible to use something like [`CreateProcessWithLogonW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) - but that requires knowing user's credentials.

Is there any way to restart / send some signal to explorer so it will know that it needs to restart / re-read SRP rules?

---

UPD: just for the reference if someone is looking for the hints:

- https://gist.github.com/LiamHaworth/1ac37f7fb6018293fc43f86993db24fc
- and copy if the original vanishes: https://gist.github.com/jdevelop/22c59371a0747918d9b43d65add1fb75

Comment: you can use `CreateProcessAsUserW`. take token from explorer before kill it

Comment: @RbMm thanks, is there any specific requirements to get the token from a running process?

Comment: no, you can take token and from session via `WTSQueryUserToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run from service you in most case (if service not special restricted) will have `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege. as result you can call [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) for obtain the primary access token of the logged-on user specified by the session ID. the *explorer* run exactly with this token. and you can use [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) for start *explorer* again with this token (again i assume your service not restricted and have `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privilege.). so you can enumerate all user terminal sessions with [`WTSEnumerateSessionsW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw) function, got token for every session, found explorer in session and restart it.

but here question how found explorer process(es). of course we can do this by short file name. enumerate all processes. but i think more reliable way will be call [`GetShellWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getshellwindow) and then [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid). but we can not do this direct from service. this need do exactly from user session(s). so possible solution - first launch self exe in every terminal session, with special command line as marker, and then already from session call [`GetShellWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getshellwindow) and restart explorer with simply [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) call

```
WCHAR ExeName[MAX_PATH];
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };

static const WCHAR tagCmdLine[] = L"|";

if (wcscmp(GetCommandLineW(), tagCmdLine))
{
    GetModuleFileNameW(0, ExeName, _countof(ExeName));

    if (GetLastError() == NOERROR)
    {
        ULONG Count;
        PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionInfo;
        if (WTSEnumerateSessionsW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &Count))
        {
            if (Count)
            {
                pSessionInfo += Count;
                do 
                {
                    HANDLE hToken;
                    if (WTSQueryUserToken((--pSessionInfo)->SessionId, &hToken))
                    {
                        PVOID lpEnvironment;
                        if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpEnvironment, hToken, FALSE))
                        {
                            if (CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, ExeName, const_cast<PWSTR>(tagCmdLine), 
                                0, 0, 0, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, 0, &si, &pi))
                            {
                                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                            }
                            DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hToken);
                    }
                } while (--Count);
            }

            WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (HWND hwnd = GetShellWindow())
    {
        ULONG dwProcessId, dwThreadId;

        if (dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId))
        {
            if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE|SYNCHRONIZE|
                PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId))
            {
                ULONG cch = _countof(ExeName);
                if (QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, 0, ExeName, &cch))
                {
                    PostThreadMessageW(dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

                    if (WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 ||
                        TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0) || 
                        RtlGetLastNtStatus() == STATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING)
                    {
                        if (CreateProcessW(ExeName, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                        {
                            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                        }
                    }
                }
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately we can't ask users to start anything upon logon, so the only option seems to enumerate all processes, find "explorer.exe", get token of each of the processes by process ID if possible, kill and then start the process. The tricky part here is that we have to do this in Go, but I guess we can figure it out.

Comment: @jdevelop - i assume that you have service

Comment: Correct, we have a windows service that we need to enhance a bit.